# Rhythmbox doesn't change files on iPod (Lubuntu 16.04)

Tags: lubuntu, rhythmbox, ipod

I'm having some ipod/mp3 issues.

I have Audacious and GNOME mplayer which don't seem to be able to add mp3 files to an ipod, but they play files just fine.

I want to drag and drop mp3 files from the disk to the ipod, so I decided to try Rhythmbox. It detects both of my ipods (3rd generation nano and 5th generation nano) and lets me add the music, but after it syncs and I disconnect, the added music doesn't show.

I installed Rhythmbox straight from the Lubuntu Software Center and have changed nothing since the install, so is something important missing? What should I do?

Thanks!

edit: I did some more googling and apparently this happens because Rhythmbox thinks the ipod is a mass storage device (and not an ipod). Thus the music is IN the ipod, but doesn't appear in the songs folder. I'm still not sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

From [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone) -

> A number of music players may or may not interface with an iPod.
>
> **Rhythmbox** - Although Rhythmbox will list the iPod on the left sidebar
>   in its Devices section, it will not show any playlists that are on the
>   iPod so **you will need another Linux tool to load the files into the
>   iPod**'s playlists.
>
> **Banshee** - Banshee's integration with the iPod is much better than
>   Rhythmbox. The iPod shows up in the left sidebar in the Devices
>   section and you can drag-and-drop playlists on top of the iPod device
>   and it will load in the files names into the library, convert them to
>   a format suitable for the iPod and synchronize between the iPod and
>   Banshee all very smoothly without crashing as gtkpod does. What it
>   does not do is manage iPod playlists as it cannot see them. **For
>   getting tracks into the iPod it is very efficient**.
>
> Of all the music players, most are basic players, some like Rhythmbox
>   and Banshee offer better integration with the iPod, but ultimately
>   gtkpod is needed to manage the iPod.

In short, **gtkpod** and **Banshee** can be used to get tracks onto the iPod, but Rhythmbox cannot. More information at the link above.

Comment: That's not true. I used Rhythmbox to copy all files to my iPod classic. I came here because it stoped working in Lubuntu 18.